# CI/CD with two heroku apps and branches in Gitlab

Tags: node.js, heroku, gitlab, gitlab-ci, heroku-ci

I want to have one repo and two heroku apps connected to it
and have the branches in my repo point to the apps for CI/CD
example: the main branch is for the herokuapp "live-prod" and the dev branch is for the herokuapp "live-dev"
any time i push changes to one of the branches I want the code pushed to live
The repo is hosted on gitlab
In the root of my nodeJS project I have a file called `.gitlab-ci.yml` with the following contents

```yaml
heroku_deploy:
  stage: production
  script:
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_APP_NAME_LIVE_PROD --api-key=$HEROKU_PRODUCTION_KEY
```

But I take this only works for one branch. How do I make it check what branch I am pushing to
so I can set **--app** to `HEROKU_APP_NAME_LIVE_PROD` or `HEROKU_APP_NAME_LIVE_DEV`